# Magento 2 : Adding multiple configurable product variations in cart

Tags: magento2, multiple-add-to-cart

I'm trying to add multiple variations of a configurable product to the cart at once, and I've put the code together, but currently it's adding the right qty of products, but only using the first variation.

In other words, if I try to add 2 Green T-Shirts and 4 White T-Shirts, It's adding 6 Green T-Shirts into cart.

This is the code I've got inside add controller:

```
public function execute()
    {
        $paramsData = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        try {
            $msg = array();
            $errorMsg = array();
            foreach($paramsData['qty'] as $pId=>$param){ 

                if (isset($param)) {
                    $filter = new \Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                        ['locale' => $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface')->getLocale()]
                    );
                    $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($param);
                }

                $params['product'] = $paramsData['product'][$pId];
                $product = $this->initProduct($params['product']);   
                $params['super_attribute'] = $paramsData['super'][$pId]; 
                /**
                 * Check product availability
                 */
                if (!$product) {
                    return $this->goBack();
                }            

                $this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);
                $msg[] = $product->getName(); 
            }             

            $this->cart->save();

        }         
        $resultRedirect->setPath('checkout/cart');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
```

And from that print_r, it's confirming that the options are correct:

```
 Array ( [super_attribute] => Array ( [90] => 5 ) [qty] => 2 ) 

 Array ( [super_attribute] => Array ( [90] => 7 ) [qty] => 4 )
```

But in the cart I'm seeing 6 of the first super_attribute(6 green T-Shirts instead of 2 green and 4 white t-shirt).

Is there something I need to do to 'reset' the cart after adding each item or something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have got answer,
issue is product object override next loop,
 in controller,

we have to create each time new product object and now its working after doing below changes.

Instead of `$product = $this->initProduct($params['product']);`we have set below line,

```
$storeId = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore()->getId();
$product = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($params['product']);
```

Its works.

Comment: Good Answer, This one saved my time! Thank You! @Rakesh

Comment: Hi Rakesh i want to add configurable product in cart from listing page. can you help me

Comment: @Rakesh can you answer for this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/201931/configurable-not-adding-to-cart-in-magento2-1-9?noredirect=1#comment279795_201931

Comment: but if use this code will made process add cart slow when add much items.

Comment: Hi Rakesh, I need to add multiple products with multiple sizes on the Category page at once? Can you help me please?

Comment: still not working for me Rakesh Jesadiya.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/364860/not-adding-separately-magento-2-adding-multiple-configurable-product-variation

Answer (score 1):

Old question, just to report a better way to do the same. Instead of using **ObjectManager**...

```
$product = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($params['product']);
```

Using **\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory** (sou you'll need to add that new dependency to your class constructor) will produce the same result...

```
$product = $this->_productFactory->create()->setStoreId($storeId)->load($params['product']);
```