# Add options to quote programmaticaly

Tags: magento2, quote, programmatically, dropdown-attribute, option

I'm creating quote and order programmaticaly.

I can't figure out why options product are not added to my order / quote.

See :

```
$superAttr = $item["super_attribute"];
if(!empty($superAttr)){
    $opts = [];
    foreach ($superAttr as $va) {
        foreach ($va as $k => $v) {
            $opts[$k] = $v;
        }
    }
    $temp = array(
        "product_id" => $product->getId(),
        "qty" => $qty,
        "super_attribute" => $opts,
    );
    $buyRequest = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject($temp);
    $this->nice($buyRequest);
    $quote->addProduct($product,$buyRequest);
}else{
    $quote->addProduct(
        $product,
        $qty);
}
```

And my $buyRequest :

```
Magento\Framework\DataObject Object(
    [_data:protected] => Array(
        [product_id] => 1739
        [qty] => 1
        [super_attribute] => Array( //keys = id of the options
            [56] => 325 //multiselect id option value
            [58] => 339 // dropdown id option value
            [57] => 334 //dropodow id option value
            [61] => Semaine 20 //textfield
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `'selected_configurable_option'` parameter in your **$buyRequest**, this parameter should include **product_id** of the simple product which match all selected configurable options

You can check [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/232628/magento2-programatically-add-to-cart-multiple-configurable-products) a piece of working code for programmatically add to cart configurable products

Comment: It seems to be for the cart, not for the quote. Will this works for the quote ? (i'm trying this right now)

Comment: I suppose it should work, as the result of adding a product to cart will result the same in quote assigned to cart

Comment: Thanks but can't make it works

Comment: Are you sure all that attributes inside 'super_attribute' are really attributes used for configurable products? I don't think text attributes are allowed for that (nor multiselect)

Comment: Yes, I've dumped the result of a query that fetch the options data